# R fisher.test print only p-value

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the fisher.test function, which is called from a perl script (using R::bridge). However, I'm only interested in the p-value output. Is there a way to capture just the p-val, and ignore (or not print) everything else?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the values returned by a call to the `fisher.test()` function (see `help(fisher.test)` in R), you will notice that there is `p.value` among others. So you just need to use `$p.value` on your R object. Here is an example, in R:

```
tab <- replicate(2, sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, rep=TRUE))
fisher.test(table(tab[,1], tab[,2]))$p.value
```

Comment: Another way of checking the structure of the "output" is by function `str`, e.g. `str(my.fisher.test.result)` That way you can see right away which list elements (in this case) are available.